# How to check that the order of elements is not changed in Json

Tags: javascript, json

SO, i am trying to make a backend test in postman that will test the elements displayed on a page and the order of the elements, for example:

Lets say i have a web page that has the "Browse pages" functionality implemented and you can switch between 5 element to be displayed or 10 elements to be displayed on the page (this in frontend).

In the back-end test i first make a request to get the first 5 elements : 1,2,3,4,5 
Then i make the request to get the 10 elements : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I often found that some of the first five elements were mixed with the next 5 element when making the second request and appear something like this 2,3,4,6,5,1,7,8,9,10

I want to make a test that will verify that the first 5 elements will remain as the first 5 and will not get mixed once the number of elements to be displayed from 5 to 10 will change. 
How can i create such a function with javascript?

Json example before with 5 elements

```
[ { "username": "1" } 
, { "username": "2" } 
, { "username": "3" } 
, { "username": "4" } 
, { "username": "5" } 
]
```

Json example after with 10 elements

```
[ { "username": "4"  } 
, { "username": "2"  } 
, { "username": "3"  } 
, { "username": "6"  } 
, { "username": "5"  } 
, { "username": "1"  } 
, { "username": "7"  } 
, { "username": "9"  } 
, { "username": "8"  } 
, { "username": "10" } 
]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: try to share with details your postman efforts

Comment: Sounds like your back end does not simulate a 'order by' clause you'd see in a sql query. Or that it chunks the requests and does not combine them again in order. Any more information? Worst case you can use `.sort()` on the client side to fix the order again. So I would prefer fixing the problem that the data is not sorted as it arrives, instead of writing a checker to see if you have to `.sort()` or not.

Comment: Use `.filter()` to filter the 10 element array to get the remaining 5. ``.concat`` the first 5 with the remaining 5 to get the new 10 element array

Comment: @ScottHunter, well,  no, i tried to look over some things and tried to solve it myself, but since i made  an account here just to ask this question means i did some efforts, and i couldn't resolve it myself

Comment: If you show what you tried, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this function it will return true if same

```
const isSame = (arr1, arr2) => {
  return !arr1.some((item, index) => {
    return item.username !== arr2[index].username 
  });
}

var arr1 = [
  { "username": "1" },
  { "username": "2" },
  { "username": "3" },
  { "username": "4" },
  { "username": "5" } 
];

var arr2 = [
  { "username": "4"  },
  { "username": "2"  },
  { "username": "3"  },
  { "username": "4"  },
  { "username": "5"  },
  { "username": "6"  },
  { "username": "7"  },
  { "username": "9"  },
  { "username": "8"  },
  { "username": "10" }
];

isSame (arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you need a function that tests your scenario.

```
function testFirstFive(initial, second) {
  let result = true;

  initial.forEach((element, index) => {
    console.log('comparing', element.username, 'with',  second[index].username);
    if (element.username !== second[index].username) {
      result = false;
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Initial is your first five elements array, second is your second ten elements array. the function will check the first array elements against the second one and return true/false whether they match or not.

Answer (score 0):

About: " I want to make a test that will verify that the first 5 elements will remain as the first 5 and will not get mixed once the number of elements to be displayed from 5 to 10 will change. How can i create such a function with javascript? "

```js
var Origin=
      [ { "username": "1" } 
      , { "username": "2" } 
      , { "username": "3" } 
      , { "username": "4" } 
      , { "username": "5" } 
      ]
  , Melting=
      [ { "username": "4"  } 
      , { "username": "2"  } 
      , { "username": "3"  } 
      , { "username": "6"  } 
      , { "username": "5"  } 
      , { "username": "1"  } 
      , { "username": "7"  } 
      , { "username": "9"  } 
      , { "username": "8"  } 
      , { "username": "10" } 
      ] 

for(let i=Origin.length;i--;)
  { 
  let pos = Melting.findIndex(e=>e.username===Origin[i].username)

  if(pos>0)
    {
    Melting.splice( pos, 1 )
    Melting.unshift( Origin[i] );
    }
  }

// verif :
for( let elm of Melting) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(elm)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; }
```